# Add app launcher to android notification menu menu

Tags: java, android, flutter

I would like to add an option to launch my app video the android pull down menu/notification bar. I have attached screenshots of this:[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Image 1 shows the pull down menu I'm referring to. Image 2 shows where I would like my app launcher to be. Is there any possible way of doing this using either regular Java for Android or the Flutter SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you are looking to add an option where you see "Huawei Share", "Screenshot", etc., that requires you to implement [a `TileService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService). I do not know whether Flutter supports this, but you can definitely implement one in Java or Kotlin.

[This class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v9.0/Introspection/SAWMonitor/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/sawmonitor/ToggleTileService.java) implements a `TileService`, though the example is rather old.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I was doubting if this is possible at all.